# iPad iOS 7 bug? Three-liner text in push notifications overlap the pull-down indicator

Tags: ipad, ios, notifications

I've noticed this on my iPad Mini (Retina), and I've tried to search for this "bug" elsewhere but found nothing which makes me suspect I'm the only one who's experiencing this? Whenever the push notification text is >= 3-lines, it overlaps with the "pull-down" indicator for the Notification Center. This is not a problem on my iPhone (same iOS version).

Any help or insights on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Screenshot from an iPad Mini Retina with iOS 7.1]

Comment: What happens when you pull down that?
Is the notification center's bottom broken?
I have that issue

Answer (score 1):

This bug also occurs on my iPhone 4 running iOS 7.1.2. I think it's a common bug.

I speculate in iOS 7, developers weren't able to send more than 2-line push notifications but in iOS 8 the feature was added iOS 7 devices also got these bigger notifications, resulting in unexpectedly large pushes (Apple stopped development of iOS 7 several years ago).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the bug as well. It's not something we have the ability to change other than suppressing the notifications.